# Variable not getting monkeypatched

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, monkeypatching

I have an issue with monkeypatching a variable I'm creating in `__init__.py`, which is actually a module - `IPython`. I try to import it there, and if it's not available, set the name to `None`. I later use that exact variable in other files by importing it from the package. However, I'm writing the tests, and I'm trying to mock (monkeypatch) `IPython`, but it appears that it remains `None` for some reason, because my tests fail with the AssertionError.

My code is structured like this:

```
pyhstr
  - __init__.py
  - application.py
  - user_interface.py
  - utilities.py
tests
  - __init__.py
  - fixtures.py
  - test_utilities.py
```

Have a look at the code:

```
# pyhstr/__init__.py

try:
    import IPython
except (ImportError, ModuleNotFoundError):
    IPython = None
```

---

```
# pyhstr/utilities.py

from pyhstr import IPython

def is_ipython() -> bool:
    assert IPython is not None
    return IPython.get_ipython() is not None
```

---

```
# tests/fixtures.py
import pyhstr

class FakeIPython:
    def get_ipython(self):
        return self


@pytest.fixture
def fake_ipython(monkeypatch):
    fake_ipy = FakeIPython()
    monkeypatch.setattr(pyhstr, 'IPython', fake_ipy)
    return fake_ipy
```

---

pytest output:

```
$ pytest -s
=================================================================================== test session starts ===================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.5, pytest-6.1.2, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/alex/.repos/pyhstr, configfile: pyproject.toml, testpaths: tests
plugins: cov-2.10.1
collected 0 items / 1 error                                                                                                                                                               

========================================================================================= ERRORS ==========================================================================================
________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_utilities.py _________________________________________________________________________
tests/test_utilities.py:3: in <module>
    from pyhstr import utilities
pyhstr/__init__.py:13: in <module>
    from pyhstr.application import SHELL, main
pyhstr/application.py:21: in <module>
    SHELL = detect_shell()
pyhstr/utilities.py:92: in detect_shell
    if is_ipython():
pyhstr/utilities.py:81: in is_ipython
    assert IPython is not None
E   AssertionError

----------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.8.5-final-0 -----------
Name                       Stmts   Miss  Cover
----------------------------------------------
pyhstr/application.py        134    127     5%
pyhstr/user_interface.py      97     69    29%
pyhstr/utilities.py           65     36    45%
----------------------------------------------
TOTAL                        296    232    22%

================================================================================= short test summary info =================================================================================
ERROR tests/test_utilities.py - AssertionError
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
==================================================================================== 1 error in 0.12s =====================================================================================

# tests/test_utilities.py
from tests.fixtures import fake_ipython

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "shell", [
        utilities.Shell.STANDARD,
        utilities.Shell.IPYTHON,
        utilities.Shell.BPYTHON,
    ]
)
def test_detect_shell(shell, fake_ipython):
    assert utilities.detect_shell() == shell
```

I've tried to move `IPython` import across the package, however, the AssertionError persists - the variable is None for some reason, despite getting monkeypatched.

How can I overcome the issue?

Comment: import the module inside the test ?

Answer (score 0):

from the [doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/monkeypatch.html):

> monkeypatch.setattr must be called before the function which will use
> the patched function is called.

on your example,

```
# tests/fixtures.py
import pyhstr
```

calls the function `__init__.py` that import the real `Ipython` before the patching takes place.

As a solution, you should `setatrr` before `import pyhstr`

Comment: I'm not sure how am I supposed to accomplish that. Can you show an example?

Comment: Set what attr, when nothing is imported?